# Efficiently Finding Weighted Integer Partitions

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, combinatorics, algorithm, counting

Suppose we have some list of natural numbers $\{ 1, 2, \dots, N \}$ and each natural number $i$ has a 'weight' $w_i$. I would like to generate the all the integer partitions which satisfy the following conditions:

1. The partition sums to less than or equal to $M$,
2. The partition has length less than or equal to $K$,
3. The partition has weight which sums to less than or equal to $W$.
4. The entries of the partition are in descending order.
5. The allowed entries of partitions are those in our list of natural numbers $\{ 1, 2, \dots, N \}$.

For instance suppose our list of natural numbers is $\{ 1, 2, 3 \}$ with weights $\{ 2, 3, 5 \}$ and we have $M=4,K=2, W=8$. In this case $\left( 1, 3 \right)$ is a partition with total weight $2+5=7$ so would be included. However $\left( 1, 1, 1 \right)$ has more than $K=2$ entries so is invalid. Similarly $\left( 3, 3 \right)$ has total weight $5+5=10$ which is over our limit $W=8$ and has sum $3+3=6$ which is also over our limit of $M=4$. Finally $\left( 4 \right)$ is an invalid partition because it involves a number outside our list $\{ 1, 2, 3 \}$.

Using the given example, I tried:

```
list = {1, 2, 3};
weights = {2, 3, 5};
M = 2;
K = 4;
W = 8;

checkWeight[partition_, weight_] := 
  Sum[weight[[partition[[i]]]], {i, 1, Length[partition]}] <= W;

allPartitions = 
 Flatten[Table[IntegerPartitions[i, K, list], {i, 1, M}], 1]

myPartitions = 
 Table[If[checkWeight[allPartitions[[i]], weights], 
   allPartitions[[i]], Nothing], {i, 1, M}]
```

The trouble is the numbers I am working with in practice look more like

```
list = Table[i, {i, 1, 25}];
weights = Table[Mod[i, 5] + 1, {i, 1, 25}];
M = Length[list]*K;
K = 5;
W = 5;
```

In this case allPartitions contains approximately $140,000$ elements while myPartitions contains $23$ elements. Consequently I'd like to find an alternative solution that doesn't waste resources computing so many unnecessary elements only to throw almost all of them away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `Solve` can deal with this problem directly.

```
list = Range[25];
weights = Mod[list, 5] + 1;
k = 5;
m = Length[list] * k;
w = 5;
```

Define a vector $\vec{v}$ whose coefficients $c_i$ count how many times the element $i$ appears in the solution:

```
v = Array[c, Length[list]];
```

Solve for the vector $v$ to find all 786 solutions:

```
s = SolveValues[1 <= Total[v] <= k &&
                list . v <= m &&
                weights . v <= w,
                v, NonNegativeIntegers]

(*    {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2},
       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3},
       ...
       {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
       {2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}    *)
```

To convert these solutions into the form you want:

```
Reverse[Join @@ MapThread[ConstantArray, {list, #}]] & /@ s

(*    {{25}, {25, 25}, {25, 25, 25}, {25, 25, 25, 25}, {25, 25, 25, 25, 25},
       {24}, {23}, {25, 23}, {22}, {25, 22}, {25, 25, 22}, {21},
       ...
       {5, 5, 5, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}, {25, 1, 1}, {20, 1, 1}, {15, 1, 1}, {10, 1, 1}, {5, 1, 1}}    *)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks!